# Problem with Particle and OpenGL, nothing is drawn

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm learning OpenGL and I'm trying to implement some particles in my application.

To do so, I followed some courses.

But when I try to render my particles, nothing happen, it doesn't even enter the shader (I tried to put some infinite loop in it and nothing happened). I tried a lot of thing, maybe there is something I did not understand..

I created a class Particle, with a constructor, an update and a draw method, I followed every step of the course, and adapted it to my class (the course is doing everything in the main loop).

My particles class got some private members:

```
private:

    size_t maxSize_;

    std::vector<float> quadData_;
    unsigned int dataVbo_;

    std::vector<float> posData_;
    unsigned int posVbo_;

    std::vector<float> colorData_;
    unsigned int colorVbo_;


    std::list<Particle> allParticles_;
```

and here is the initialization of `Particles`:

```
Particles::Particles(size_t maxSize)
: maxSize_(maxSize), quadData_({-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f})
{

    posData_.resize(maxSize_*4);
    colorData_.resize(maxSize_*4);


    glGenBuffers(1, &dataVbo_);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataVbo_);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadData_.size() * sizeof(float), quadData_.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    // The VBO containing the positions and sizes of the particles
    glGenBuffers(1, &posVbo_);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVbo_);
    // Initialize with empty (NULL) buffer : it will be updated later, each frame.
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, maxSize_ * 4 * sizeof(float), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    // The VBO containing the colors of the particles
    glGenBuffers(1, &colorVbo_);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVbo_);
    // Initialize with empty (NULL) buffer : it will be updated later, each frame.
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, maxSize_ * 4 * sizeof(float), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

}
```

and the draw:

```
void Particles::draw(){


    size_t count(posData_.size());

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVbo_);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, maxSize_ * 4 * sizeof(float), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW); // Buffer orphaning, a common way to improve streaming perf. See above link for details.
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, count * sizeof(float), posData_.data());

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVbo_);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, maxSize_ * 4 * sizeof(float), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW); // Buffer orphaning, a common way to improve streaming perf. See above link for details.
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, count * sizeof(float) * 4, colorData_.data());


    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataVbo_);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);

    // 2nd attribute buffer : positions of particles' centers
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVbo_);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);

    // 3rd attribute buffer : particles' colors
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVbo_);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);

    glVertexAttribDivisor(0, 0); // particles vertices : always reuse the same 4 vertices -> 0
    glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 1); // positions : one per quad (its center) -> 1
    glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1); // color : one per quad -> 1

    glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4, count);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
}
```

And in my main loop I'm doing this:

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    myParticules.update(elapsedTime);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glUseProgram(_particleShad);

    myParticles.draw();
```

I'm also sending some uniform vec and mat, but nothing important.

In my shader I only try to do this:

```
Vertex :
    gl_Position = vec4(squareVertices.xyz, 1);
        //squareVertices contain the vertices of my square for my particles

Fragment :
        color = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

I don't find anything wrong, I really need some help, I'm totally lost.

Comment: Try enabling alpha blending and enabling visibility of back-facing polygons

Comment: Sorry, should have mentionned it, but I allready did this, I tryied a lot of little option, but nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a VAO (Vertex Array Object):

```
class Particles {
private:
     // add:
     GLuint vao;
     ...
```

Initialization:

```
Particles::Particles(size_t maxSize)
: maxSize_(maxSize), quadData_({-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f})
{

    posData_.resize(maxSize_*4);
    colorData_.resize(maxSize_*4);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &dataVbo_);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataVbo_);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadData_.size() * sizeof(float), quadData_.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);


    // The VBO containing the positions and sizes of the particles
    glGenBuffers(1, &posVbo_);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVbo_);
    // Initialize with empty (NULL) buffer : it will be updated later, each frame.
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, maxSize_ * 4 * sizeof(float), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);

    // The VBO containing the colors of the particles
    glGenBuffers(1, &colorVbo_);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVbo_);
    // Initialize with empty (NULL) buffer : it will be updated later, each frame.
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, maxSize_ * 4 * sizeof(float), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);


    glVertexAttribDivisor(0, 0); // particles vertices : always reuse the same 4 vertices -> 0
    glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 1); // positions : one per quad (its center) -> 1
    glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1); // color : one per quad -> 1
}
```

Drawing code:

```
void Particles::draw(){
    size_t count(posData_.size());

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVbo_);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, count * sizeof(float), posData_.data());

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVbo_);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, count * sizeof(float) * 4, colorData_.data());

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4, count);
}
```

Notice how you don't need to update your VAO state during the `draw()` call, only during the initialization.